# Java JLS, the supertype set of a type

Tags: java, type-inference, jls

This [section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.4) of the JLS describes what ST(U) is, where U is a type:

> Let ST(Ui) be the set of supertypes of Ui.

And a few lines under that, in the same section, there is an example:

> For example, given List<String> and List<Object>, simply intersecting the sets ST(List<String>) = { List<String>, Collection<String>, Object } and ST(List<Object>) = { List<Object>, Collection<Object>, Object } would yield a set { Object }, and we would have lost track of the fact that the upper bound can safely be assumed to be a List.

Shouldn't ST(List<String>) also include Iterable<String>?

Comment: Yeah, that looks like an error in the JLS section.

Comment: Come to think of it, `List` and all its supertypes should also be in `ST(List<String>)`, since by [section 4.10.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.2), `List` is a direct supertype of `List<String>`. This example doesn't really work.

Comment: List is not in ST(List<String>) because well... it's in EST(List<String>), EST is the erased super type set.

Comment: No, the fact that it's in the EST doesn't preclude it from being in the ST.

Comment: Right above that: "*The reason for computing the set of erased supertypes is to deal with situations where the set of types includes several distinct parameterizations of a generic type.*" - It's a demonstration. They didn't intend to specify all possible supertypes. They're simply expressing how intersecting an erased set allows persistence of the type `List`, opposed to intersecting a set with different paramerterizations. They didn't need to include `Iterable` to express their point.

Comment: Note that the set of supertypes of a parameterized type is often infinite. For example, `List<String>` has the supertype `List<? extends Comparable<String>>`, which in turn has the supertype `List<? extends Comparable<? extends Comparable<String>>>`, and so on. (I stumbled over this in [some utility function for supertype computations](https://github.com/javagl/Types/blob/master/src/main/java/de/javagl/types/Supertypes.java#L173) ). The example in the JLS is likely only for illustrative purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, `ST(List<String>)` should contain `Iterable<String>`. Moreover, `ST(List<String>)` should contain `List` and all supertypes of `List`, since by [JLS 8 Section 4.10.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.2),

> Given a generic type declaration `C<F1,...,Fn>` (n > 0), the direct supertypes of the parameterized type `C<T1,...,Tn>`, where Ti (1 ≤ i ≤ n) is a type, are all of the following:
>
> - ...
> - The raw type C.

so this example doesn't actually demonstrate what it's trying to demonstrate, because `List` actually is in the intersection of `ST(List<String>)` and `ST(List<Object>)`, before ESTs come into the picture.

I think the example may have been written for an earlier version of the supertyping rules and then not updated when the rules changed. The Java 7 JLS [defines the supertype relationship differently](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.2), but even then, I think `Iterable<String>` would have been a supertype of `List<String>`.